# Can't cd to directory which has spaces in the name

Tags: macos, git, terminal

I am trying to make my first commit in git from the terminal, however the file that I am trying to commit apparently does not exist... but it does. When I run `ls` I can see it in the listed documents. It is a folder named `Portland Code School Example` in the folder `/Users/SP_Desktop1/dropbox/coding`. It has a simple index.html webpage inside.

When I try to navigate inside the folder (after verifying that I'm in the `coding` file using `pwd`) by using `cd Portland Code School Example` it returns `-bash: cd: portland: No such file or directory`

I am able to `cd` into other files from the `coding` file, but for some reason I can't enter the `Portland Code School Example` folder. I figure that once I am inside I can stage the `index.html` file to commit it to github.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Might be worthwhile taking a step back and learning a bit more about the shell and command line in general this is a good place to start. http://linuxcommand.org/

Comment: You might also like to try *tab completion*, where you start typing enough for the shell to work out what you mean, then hit the <TAB> key (left side of keyboard above <SHIFT>) and it guesses.... try typing `cd Port<TAB>`

Comment: You can also use wildcards to avoid having to deal with spaces, try typing `cd Por*ple`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that there are spaces in the name of the directory to which you're trying to navigate. Escape spaces with `\` when `cd`ing:

```
 > cd Portland\ Code\ School\ Example
```

Or wrap the directory name in quotes:

```
 > cd "Portland Code School Example"
```

Answer (score 0):

Space is the problem. It is always good to use underscores (Portland_Code_School_Example) when creating directories but for this you can use tab key

eg Portland tabkey